# Call PHP script inside a function via return

Tags: php

I am working on integrating two wordpress plugins. What I am trying to do is to add this code`<?php DisplayStars(get_the_ID()); ?>` into a function of another plugin. I tried `$html = '<?php DisplayStars(get_the_ID()); ?>';`, but php shows errors. Thanks for your help.

```
function wpbusdirman_post_excerpt($count)
{   
    $wpbusdirman_gpid=wpbusdirman_gpid();
    $wpbusdirman_permalink=get_permalink($wpbusdirman_gpid);
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div id="wpbdmlistings"';
    $isasticky = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'sticky');
    if(isset($isasticky) && !empty($isasticky))
    {
        $isasticky=$isasticky[0];
    }
    if(isset($isasticky) && ($isasticky == 'approved'))
    {
        if($count&1)
        {
            $html .= ' class="wpbdmoddsticky"';
        }
        else 
        {
            $html .= ' class="wpbdmevensticky"';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if($count&1)
        {
            $html .= ' class="wpbdmodd"';
        }
        else 
        {
            $html .= ' class="wpbdmeven"';
        }
    }
    $html .='><div class="listingthumbnail">' . wpbusdirman_display_the_thumbnail() . '</div><div class="listingdetails">';
    $html .= wpbusdirman_display_the_listing_fields();
    $html .= wpbusdirman_view_edit_delete_listing_button();
    $html .= '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code. Please try to format it better when you next post some code. thanks :-)

Comment: I don't see `DisplayStars` in your code anywhere..

Comment: @tandu - when I add the code $html = '<?php DisplayStars(get_the_ID()); ?>' inside the function, it actually did not has output. But I can see the php code by checking the html source code. Do I need to put a PHP include? Thanks.

Comment: woo boy, I think you may not understand what PHP is. If you can see the php code in your html source code you've already done something wrong. `$html = '<?php DisplayStars(get_the_ID()); ?>'` will create a string equal to <?php DisplayStars(get_the_ID()); ?>, but it won't run the function. If you're already inside a PHP function, you should not re-declare your PHP tags (`<?php`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code base you're working in is php.  The code you're adding is php.  That means, you don't need to add it inside the html, but simply call the function.  (You may need an [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) at the top of the file for the function to work if it's not in this file)

```
$html .= DisplayStars(get_the_ID());
```

should be all you need in the call to add the text to the html.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like this:

```
<?php return "<?php echo('foo'); ?>"; ?>
```

Then PHP doesn't know (or care) about what is between the quotation marks - it's just text, as far as it knows. However, you can get PHP to interpret a string by using `eval`:

```
<?php
    $command = "echo('foo');";
    eval($command);
?>
```

This will cause PHP to print out "foo". But watch out, `eval` is dangerous - see the [note in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).